How can I turn "Copy only when installing" option using Tuist setup
I'm currently converting my project using tuist which has 2 extensions. After generate with tuist, Main app target configured like pic1 attached below. but to compile and run my app successfully I need to turn Copy only when installing option on. Is there any way to turn this option on tuist edit project? I have tried couple of days to configure using tuist edit, still failing to configure it. Anyone could help me?

[updated] tuist configurations for extension targests
private static func makeExtensionTargets(
        name: String,
        appBundleId: String,
        bundleIdPostFix: String) -> [Target]
    {
        if name == "ext-notiservice" {
            let source = Target.target(
                name: name,
                destinations: .iOS,
                product: .appExtension,
                bundleId: "\(appBundleId).\(bundleIdPostFix)",
                deploymentTargets: .iOS("14.0"),
                infoPlist: .file(path: .relativeToRoot("Targets/\(name)/Supporting Files/Info.plist")),
                sources: ["Targets/\(name)/Sources/**"],
                entitlements: .file(path: .relativeToRoot("Targets/\(name)/Supporting Files/\(name).entitlements")),
                dependencies: [
                    .xcframework(path: .relativeToRoot("Targets/\(name)/frameworks/BrazeNotificationService.xcframework")),
                ]
            )
            return [source]
        } else if name == "ext-noticontent" {
            let sources = Target.target(
                name: name,
                destinations: .iOS,
                product: .appExtension,
                bundleId: "\(appBundleId).\(bundleIdPostFix)",
                deploymentTargets: .iOS("14.0"),
                infoPlist: .file(path: .relativeToRoot("Targets/\(name)/Supporting Files/Info.plist")),
                sources: ["Targets/\(name)/Sources/**"],
                resources: ["Targets/\(name)/Resources/**/*.*"],
                dependencies: [.xcframework(path: .relativeToRoot("Targets/\(name)/frameworks/BrazePushStory.xcframework"))]
            )
            return [sources]
        }
        return []
    }

[updated] error message
Unable to install "MYAPP"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
Recovery Suggestion: Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-09-09 01:36:56 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
Unable to install "MYAPP"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
Recovery Suggestion: Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built.
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
There was an internal API error.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000067)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010eb07670 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 300
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010eb342e0 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 136
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101f1799c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010eb34064 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1168
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000111f1f41c __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.151 + 2344
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102028578 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102028fa0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 152
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184a0c750 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184a0e3e8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184a15a14 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184a16544 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184a212d0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184a20b44 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000184bbb00c _pthread_wqthread + 288
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000184bb9d28 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone15,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.2 (20C65)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "397.3.5.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1757.0.0.101.1";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 12228;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402653081";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos17.5";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.5";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.5 (Build 23F79)
Xcode 15.4 (22622) (Build 15F31d)
Timestamp: 2024-09-09T10:36:56+09:00


Curious, why do you need to copy only when installing? What issue are you seeing if you try to compile without doing that?

When I run app without checking "copy only when installing" app crashs. I guess launcher cannot find extension binary wile launch.

Maybe you can share the error message. Cause this option is supposed to only cause the frameworks to be embedded only while installing. Not enabling this option should cause it to always copy (even while building and not installing).

Updated body with error messages. Thank you for taking an interest in my post.
